# Debugging C# application that is already built

Tags: c#, debugging

I have an application I made that I lost the source code for, but the application has worked on my Win 2K computer. Now when moving to a Windows 7 computer it won't start. Probably some dependencies that needs to be solved, but I don't know which. The only error I got is a System.InvalidOperation without further description

Is there any tools(free) that I can use to get more specific information on what goes on

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C#.Net".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how/if you can debug the application, but here is another idea.

There are tool out there called "reflectors", which allow you to look inside the .NET dll or executable.
They basically do the reverse of the compiler convert the dll/exe to source code (Now it won't be exactly the code you wrote, for example some local variables might have changed their names and some things might have been optimized, but the end result is the same, since this reflected code came from the same dll/exe.)

Now you can take the output of this and use it to rebuild and then debug your application.

Here are some ofthese tool:

1. [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) - free
2. [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) - not free

I know dotPeek doesn't allow you to debug inside of it, so you have to rebuild your application. The other one seems to be able to do that with its most expensive licence. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Microsoft Debugging Tools for Windows (`WinDbg`). Here is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers.aspx) that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dependencywalker.com/  will tell you dependencies and missing ones.

Also, you can attach visual studio, or get visual studio to launch a exe in debug mode without the source code.

Answer (score 0):

- my first try would be dependency walker just to make sure your not
  missing some piece of native code
- then I would look to just attempting to attach the program to visual 
  studio.
- My next step would be to use something like reflector to get some
  version of source code.

Answer (score 0):

The pro version of regate's [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/vspro/) let's you debug an existing dll without the sourcecode, costs $ 138 tho.

[Ilspy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) will let you see the source for free, maybe you can figure it out from that.

Rgds Gert-JAn